# Not rendering block on diffrent server (ACF + Gutenberg + Timber)

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-gutenberg

I have a problem with block rendering.

I use the connection: ACF + Timber + Gutenberg.

Creating blocks on localhost was not a problem, everything was displayed both on the wp-admin side and on the frontend side (created on Linux, PHP 7.219, nginx)

After installing for test on Windows + the latest XAMPP (PHP 7.39, apache) , it turned out that the blocks do not render (they can not be seen both on the wp-admin and the frontend site).

That's why I put it on Raspberri Pi (PHP 7.120, apache) and it started normally. I thought maybe it was a matter of Windows and some server settings. However, when installed on a normal web server (Linux, PHP 7.0.33, apache) also did not work.

Does anyone have an idea what could be the reason for the blocks not being rendered?

---

In the following function does not enter callback at all (text_block_render_callback), however register block works.

```
add_action('acf/init', 'register_block_text');
function register_block_text() {
    acf_register_block(array(
        'name' => 'text',
        'title' => ('Tekst', 'ABC'),
        'description' => ('Moduł zwykłego tekstu', 'ABC'),
        'render_callback' => 'text_block_render_callback',
        'category' => 'test-blocks',
        'icon' => 'edit',
        'keywords' => array('blog'),
        'mode' => 'edit',
        'enqueue_assets' => function() {
            wp_enqueue_style( 'block-text', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/dist/blocks/text/text.css');
        }
    ));
}

function text_block_render_callback($block, $content = '', $is_preview = false)
{
    $context = Timber::context();

    $context['block'] = $block;
    $context['fields'] = get_fields();
    $context['is_preview'] = $is_preview;

    Timber::render(TEMPLATEPATH . '/views/blocks/text/text.twig', $context);
}
```

---

**WORKING - SAME CODE**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLVUS.png (wp-admin)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zB8e4.png (frontend)

---

**NOT WORKING - SAME CODE**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbW99.png (wp-admin / view)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfeKw.png (wp-admin / edit)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5fiE.png (frontend)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you solved the problem. I use local and I have the same problem.

I used always that:

```
Timber::render( get_stylesheet_directory() . "/views/block-editor/content-{$slug}.twig", $context );
```

but that doesn't work in some servers (and the new version 5.x of local)

I use now that:

```
Timber::render( "block-editor/content-{$slug}.twig", $context );
```